# Using sudo to give access to another account on same machine

Tags: sudo, privileges

There are two unix accounts `A` and `B`.I want to execute a unix command from account `B` such that the command behaves as if it was executed from account `A` .How can I do this ?

The problem here is that how can I give privileges to the command so that it runs as an owner of account `A` but run from account `B`.Can this be done using `sudo` ? This is similar to  something like `passwd` command which when run from any account is able to alter a file `/etc/passwd` which has root as owner.

Answer (score 2):

You do this by editing `/etc/sudoers`. You must use the command `visudo` to edit this file. `visudo` will open an editor that lets you edit the file, then check for errors before saving it. Manually edit `/etc/sudoers` could break your system.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, add user specifications to the file.

B can run `cp`, `mv` and `rm` as A:

```
B ALL = (A) cp, mv, rm
```

B can run everything as A:

```
B ALL = (A) ALL
```

Same thing without password:

```
B ALL = (A) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

See `man sudoers` for more.

Comment: Does this work for self programmed commands,scripts...?

Comment: It should work if you use the full path name (`/path/to/script.sh`) instead of just `cp`, `mv` or `rm`